# Finding a sparse solution to $A x = b$ via linear programming

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, sparsity

I'm trying to solve a system $Ax = b$ where all entries of $x$ are nonnegative, and most are zero. So if $x$ has $N$ entries, then $\epsilon N$ of them are nonzero, where $\epsilon > 0$ is some small constant. Is it possible to use linear programming in this setting?

Comment: Is $\epsilon$ given?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Since you've create the tag [tag:sparsity], can you update the tag info, possibly explaining how its usage is different from [tag:sparse-matrices]?

Comment: @pjs36 Would finding a sparse solution to $\rm A x = b$ fall under the "sparse matrices" category? Yes, a column vector can be viewed as a matrix, but that is unsatisfying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to solve for $x$ where
$$\begin{align} & Ax=b \\
                & x_i\ge 0 \\
                & \sum_{i|x_i>0} 1 \le m
\end{align}$$
Counting non-zero elements is not easy in an LP, but we can use a MIP model:
$$\begin{align} & Ax=b \\
                & x_i \le M y_i \\  
                & \sum_i y_i \le m\\
                & x_i\in [0,M] \\
                & y_i \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}$$ 
where $M$ is an upper bound on $x_i$ and $y_i$ are binary variables.

This approach requires some reasonable upper bound on $x$. Otherwise many MIP solvers nowadays have a concept called `indicator variables`, allowing a model like this to be solved without a big-$M$. I.e.:

$$\begin{align} & Ax=b \\
                & y_i = 0 \Rightarrow x_i=0  \\  
                & \sum_i y_i \le m\\
                & x_i\ge 0 \\
                & y_i \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}$$